# Find the biggest of 4 numbers in Windows Batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to find the biggest of 4 numbers in batch scripting but it is not working.

The `GTR` command is not getting executed.

From this line it never gets executed `if !Counter_Senior! gtr !Max_Age! (`

I'm new to batch scripting, I am not sure about alignment and spacing. please help me through.

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a Counter_Child=1
set /a Counter_Senior=2 
set /a Counter_Older_adult=0
set /a Counter_Young_adult=3
set /a Max_Age=%counter_Child%

echo maximum age is %Max_Age%

if !Counter_Senior! gtr !Max_Age! (
    set Max_Age=%Counter_Senior%
    if !Counter_Older_adult! gtr !Max_Age! (
        set Max_Age=%Counter_Older_adult%
        if !%Counter_Young_adult! gtr !Max_Age! (
            set Max_Age=%Counter_Young_adult%
            time /t
            echo Maximum age is %Max_Age%
            goto:EOF
        )
    )
)

if !Counter_Older_adult! gtr !Max_Age! (
    set %Max_Age%=%Counter_Older_adult%
    if !%Counter_Young_adult! gtr !Max_Age! (
        set %Max_Age%=%Counter_Young_adult%
        echo Maximum age is %Max_Age% 
        goto:EOF
    )
) 

if !%Counter_Young_adult! gtr !Max_Age! (
    set %Max_Age%=%Counter_Young_adult%
    echo Maximum age is %Max_Age% 
    goto:EOF
)   

echo Maximum age is %Max_Age%

goto:EOF
```

Comment: I added some indentations and empty lines to your script to help improve it's readability. I did not change any of it's content!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems way too complicated. Try this:

```
echo off
set Counter_Child=1
set Counter_Senior=2 
set Counter_Older_adult=0
set Counter_Young_adult=3
set Max_Age=%Counter_Child%
IF %Counter_Senior% GTR %Max_Age% SET Max_Age=%Counter_Senior%
IF %Counter_Older_adult% GTR %Max_Age% SET Max_Age=%Counter_Older_adult%
IF %Counter_Young_adult% GTR %Max_Age% SET Max_Age=%Counter_Young_adult%
echo maximum age is %Max_Age%
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution to the question posed. It won't scale well to checking, for example, four hundred ages, but it's more than adequate for what's needed, and only takes four lines of code to work out the maximum age.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the maximum value of the four Counter variables then you could use this:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%A In ('Set Counter_'
) Do If %%A GEq !Max_Age! Set/A Max_Age=%%A
```

**[Edit]**
And for the scenario suggested by [Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders)…

```bat
For %%A In (
    %Counter_Child% %Counter_Senior% %Counter_Older_adult% %Counter_Young_adult%
) Do If %%A GEq !Max_Age! Set/A Max_Age=%%A
```

Comment: This is problematic if you don't control the external environment, somebody could do "Set Counter_Evil=99" before running the batch file to change its behavior.

Comment: Of course they could, _(I didn't choose the variable names, they were already given)_ but I would suggest that one can make that comment about almost any script which uses the `Set` statement. My suggestion though is that the actual end product would be propagating those values using input data, _(otherwise it serves little purpose)_, so the end user will likely have control over them anyhow. Also creating another variable beginning `Counter_` will only stop the correct answer being returned, there's no benefit in running the script if you don't want it to output the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two problems with your code:

- You are using `goto:EOF` inside a `if` and that quits the entire batch file.
- In some places you incorrectly used `set %Max_Age%=..` instead of `set Max_Age=..`

Your code is also overcomplicated and can be reduced to something simpler like the answer posted by [MichaelS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982987/3501).

If you want to print specific information when a change is made you can use a generic sub procedure:

```
@echo off
goto Start

:CheckAge 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set newage=!%1!
if %newage% gtr %Max_Age% (
    echo %1 is older than %Max_Age%, the new maximum is %newage%
    set Max_Age=%newage%
)
endlocal & set Max_Age=%Max_Age%
goto :EOF

:Start
set Counter_Child=1
set Counter_Senior=2
set Counter_Older_adult=0
set Counter_Young_adult=3
set Max_Age=0

call :CheckAge Counter_Child
call :CheckAge Counter_Senior
call :CheckAge Counter_Older_adult
call :CheckAge Counter_Young_adult
echo Maximum age is %Max_Age%
```